# The correct location of the gap in a relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, zero-relative-pronoun

On page 1037 of the Cambridge Grammar:

[image]

In [2iii] and [2iv] above is shown a gap "in object position".

In fact, this is where all the grammars that I know of would put the gap. If the gap corresponds to an object of a verb -- as here -- or of a preposition, all the grammars that I know of put it after the verb or the preposition.

But I wonder why it has to be.

If you look at [2ii], *which* is used instead of the gap in [2iii] or [2iv], and that *which* is also acting as an object there. But it isn't placed after *gave me* but is placed at the start of the relative clause.

Since the gap you can't see anyway, I wonder why the gap cannot be placed right before *my*, as follows:

> *I accepted the advice* [*that ____ my neighbour gave me*].
>
> *I accepted the advice* [*____ my neighbour gave me*].

This way, I think the structure of the relative clause might be more coherently explained and understood.

Also, does anyone know of a grammar that places the gap like this?

Comment: I think the point of putting in the gap is to show the original position of the NP that is missing in the relative clause. Since it's not there any more, it has to be imagined. It's not a great device, and it's not part of a formal theory, so don't worry about it.

Comment: @JohnLawler So there's no reason not to put it at the start of the relative clause, then.

Comment: There is a gap after "me".  "I accepted the advice which my neighbour gave me ___ ", (see P1038 [4]). Btw, I take it you realise that "that" is not a relative pronoun, but a subordinator.

Comment: @BillJ Of course, it's a suboridnator! I also know The Cambridge Grammar sometimes puts a gap even in a wh-relative clause --as in your comment-- and sometimes doesn't, as shown in the OP. But when they do, I think the gap merely shows the original place of the relativized element, which isn't necessarily the case with the gap in a _that_-relative or a bare relative.

Comment: Gap appears in _wh_ relatives where the relativised element is not subject, irrespective of whether it's a _wh_ relative or otherwise. The full analysis of [2ii] is discussed on p1038. I don't see what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I'm not a syntactician, so I'm not really familiar with the nuances of these theories and I'm not really sure what "gaps" in relative clauses are supposed to be, in a technical sense.

But BillJ's comments and linguisticturn's answer indicate that according to CGEL, it wouldn't be technically correct to say that "[in] [2ii], *which* is used **instead** of the gap in [2iii] or [2iv]". For some reason, it seems [2] presents a simplified analysis of the grammar: [2ii] actually does have a gap (after *me*) as well as the relative pronoun *which.*

I have found another source that indicates that there would be a "gap" in the wh-relative clause just as much as in the other kinds of relative clauses:

- > in a standard RC there is a double anaphoric relationship: between the head noun and the Relative Pronoun on the one hand and between the Relative Pronoun
  >   and the gap (the empty position of the deleted constituent) on the other.

  ("[European relative clauses and the uniqueness of the Relative Pronoun Type](http://www.italian-journal-linguistics.com/wp-content/uploads/Fiorentino.pdf)", by
  Giuliana Fiorentino, p. 275)

In terms of terminology, some other sources say that in wh-relatives, the relative pronoun "moves" from the original place, leaving behind a "trace". I don't know if that's different in any significant way from a "gap" resulting from a "deleted" constituent. I have the impression that the concept of "movement" has been debated a lot ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_movement) describes it as "controversial").

Chapter 11 "Wh- movement in English" of *[The syntax of natural language: An online introduction using the Trees program](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch11.html)* (Santorini, Beatrice, and Anthony Kroch. 2007-) seems to say that all English relative clauses start with a relative pronoun slot followed by a relativizer slot; the relativizer is covert in wh-relatives and the relative pronoun is covert in *that*-relatives. There is additionally a trace later on in the clause for both kinds of relative clauses.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Gap is the standard device for marking a missing constituent. Also, "that" is not a relative pronoun, but a clause subordinator, so it cannot function as a subject or object in a relative clause. Instead, these functions are marked by gap.

Comment: @BillJ: What do "device" and "missing" mean exactly? I don't think I called "that" a relative pronoun anywhere in this answer; I said "the relativizer is covert in wh-relatives and the relative pronoun is covert in that-relatives", which seems to be the situation that is shown in the diagrams given by Santorini and Kroch.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of Santorini and Kroch' s approach to the better (and more logical) one taken by H&P in their CGEL. I only mentioned the category of "that" because it is, I think, the core of the OP's problem. You simply **must** look at CGEL to see what we're talking about here. (see my last comment to the OP for the answer)

Comment: @BillJ: I think you should write an answer. I don't own CGEL so I can't check it right now. If, as you say in your comment below the question, "The full version of [2ii] is "I accepted the advice which my neighbour gave me ___ "", then why isn't the "__" included in the quotation? Is it misquoted?

Comment: No: it's because the book takes things in stages. Initially (as seen in in [2ii]) it gives a simple explanation about relativisation and the contrast between _that_ relatives and _wh_ relatives.  As the grammar progresses, it goes into more detail about gaps, and we find an explanation with examples showing gap in _wh_ relatives. I would post an answer but I think the answer to the OP's question is a simple one, i.e. that they need to look further into the chapter on r/c's. Do please try to get a copy of CGEL - does your local library have it?

Comment: @BillJ I don't think CGEL answers my question. If it did, I wouldn't even bother posting a question here. If somehow you believe that CGEL does answer my question, please give me the page number.

Comment: @JK2 Gap is inserted in its functional position, not as a replacement as such for _that_ . Compare the immediate subject gap in "This is the copy that ___ is defective" (p1084 [17i].

Answer (score 2):

The location of the gap is not negotiable. It is placed where the object would be placed in a 'canonical' (i.e. non-relativized in this case) version of the clause.

A few lines below the section you quoted (pp. 1037-1038), [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) says that, formally speaking, [2ii] also has a gap in the same place.

> Formally, there is a gap after *gave me* in this construction as well as in the non-*wh* relatives. The difference is that while in [2iii-iv] the gap is related directly to the antecedent *advice*, in [2ii] it is related indirectly, via *which*. Example [2ii] can thus be represented as in [3] …
>
> [3] *I accepted the **advice**<sub>i</sub> [**which**<sub>i</sub> my neighbour gave me ____<sub>i</sub>].*

The principle in question generalizes to cases in which the missing constituent is something other than an object. The gap always occurs where that missing constituent would be in a (more) canonical clause; see Sec. 7.2 'Gaps and antecedents' on p. 1082 of CGEL.

Comment: Then, how would you place the gap in these examples? (1) _He was wearing a tall black sheepskin hat_ [_from the top of which dangled a little red bag ornamented by a chain of worsted lace and tassels_]. (2) _I may be late,_ [_in which case I suggest you start without me_]. I mean, does it really matter what a canonical version is?

Comment: @JK2 Your first sentence serves as a good illustration of why the canonical form matters. Here is a simpler version of that sentence that will do just as well: *It was a hat [from the top of which dangled a bag]*. The non-relativized version is *From the top of the hat dangled a bag.* This is still not canonical, but a **subject-dependent inversion** of a canonical clause. What is canonical is *A bag dangled from the top of the hat.* Note that CGEL doesn't attempt to diagram such inversions (which are discussed in Ch. 16, 'Information packing'); that's for more advanced texts, I'd imagine.

Comment: @JK2 For now, let's leave the inversion as is. In that case, there would be **no gap** in this sentence. *From the top of which* is already in the correct place, and *which* could be simply replaced by its antecedent, *(the) hat*. Now you may begin to see why referring to the canonical form is helpful: if the inverted version is allowed to be the referent one, then we seem to have a contradiction of the principle that integrated relative constructions are characterized by an anaphoric gap. But if we insist on canonical versions, there is no problem.

Comment: @JK2 Here is your sentence without the inversion: *It was a hat [from the top of which a bag dangled*]. In this sentence, there is indeed a gap after *dangled*. So the full analysis of your sentence involves two phenomena (some might say two 'processes'): relativization and inversion. It's perhaps too much to expect that simple in-sentence notation would be able to describe both at the same time. You'd need more sophisticated diagramming to do that, I would think.

Comment: @JK2 Your second sentence is an example of **supplementation**, where things are a lot 'looser'. In particular, instead of **syntactic** compatibility of antecedents, all you need is **semantic** compatibility of **anchors** (p. 1351). Moreover, CGEL says that the whole *in which case* is a relative phrase (p. 756). So the non-relativized version would be something like *if I'm late I suggest you start without me*. It is not that surprising that anaphoric gaps do not really feature here: gaps are syntactical; they really require antecedents. But in supplements all you have is semantic anchors.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments. In your second comment, you seem to suggest that you don't have a gap in the inverted version, just because it's not a canonical form. But that's not true. For example, in _no candidate who scored 40% or more was ever failed_ (p1061), there's no gap in _who scored 40% or more_ even though it's a canonical form.

Comment: The semantic compatibility of the anchor in the supplementary relative clause is about the relationship between the anchor (antecedent) and the supplementary relative clause. Unlike the integrated relative clause, the supplementary relative clause does not form a syntactic unit with its anchor (antecedent). Which does not mean that the supplementary relative clause itself is somehow "loosely" formed. The existence of the gap in the relative clause has nothing to do with the type of the relative clause. That's why you can use the same relative clause for both types. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) In my second example (_I may be late,_ [_in which case I suggest you start without me_]), therefore, what is "looser" is the relationship between what's before the comma and what's after it, not the former or the latter itself. And I suspect the supplementary relative clause (_in which case I suggest you start without me_) is in canonical form and also doesn't have a gap because as an independent clause it'd be _In that case I suggest you start without me_, which is similar to your own sentence in your 2nd comment (_In that case, there would be no gap in this sentence._)